# Git clone Error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

Tags: git, clone

I am trying to clone a (private) remote repository but I am getting following error:

```
 remote: Counting objects: 11410, done
 remote: Finding sources: 100% (11410/11410)
 remote: Getting sizes: 100% (9178/9178)
 error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
 error: inflate: data stream error (invalid block type)
 fatal: pack has bad object at offset 427781: inflate returned -3
```

I am using Git version 1.9.4 on Windows 8 Pro Build 9200. There are large files on that repo, but file size seems irrelevant to my problem because I still get the same error when I try to clone some other smaller repository (<20Mb with AppHarbor).
Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like I have some problem via internet http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Problem-while-cloning-a-git-repo-td7599236.html   but I still cant understand which problems

Comment: https://appharbor.com/  You can push and deploy .Net project up to 20 mb free

Comment: What can you tell us about your network config? Have you read [this](http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/clone-fails-RPC-failed-result-56-HTTP-code-200-tp7574837p7574853.html)?

Comment: I am not sure that I can tell You something about my network config. Now I am waiting for admin. Maybe he will find some problem

Comment: Show your sysadmin the link in my comment; that may help.

Comment: Yes, sure, I will show

Comment: I use Avast, Admin turned it off. (Disable protect) and now everything is ok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My sysadmin figured out that the problem was with Avast. If you're experiencing the same problem and you use Avast, then try disabling it. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

The git binaries I've found in ubuntu and debian both have this bug. It's caused by a bug in GnuTLS which git is compiled against (tracked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/1111882)). It's simply not possible to clone a git repo in Ubuntu or Debian with a HTTPS URL.

You have two options:

1. Clone the repo using SSH
2. Recompile git against `libcurl4-openssl-dev` (`libcurl4-gnutls-dev` didn't work for me)

In case you decide for option #2, here's a copy/paste to recompile the latest git on debian or ubuntu. The latest version of git is found [here](https://github.com/git/git/releases).

```
apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev autoconf \
&& wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.8.1.tar.gz -O git.tar.gz \
&& tar -zxf git.tar.gz \
&& cd git-* \
&& make configure \
&& ./configure --prefix=/usr  \
&& make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using SSH to perform the clone. Solution found [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=693897332).

> To use SSH with Bitbucket, you create an SSH identity. An identity
>   consists of a private and a public key which together are a key pair.
>   The private key resides on your local computer and the public you
>   upload to your Bitbucket account. Once you upload a public key to your
>   account, you can use SSH to connect with repositories you own and
>   repositories owned by others, provided those other owners give your
>   account permissions. By setting up SSH between your local system and
>   the Bitbucket server, your system uses the key pair to automate
>   authentication; you won't need to enter your password each time you
>   interact with your Bitbucket repository.

Here's how to [Setup SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem on my Ubuntu environment, run export `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` solve it. [Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=693897332) is the link.

Comment: This setting will just make git console output more verbose. Possibly this will give you a hint why the error occurs, but it won't solve it.