# Git clone repository error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

Tags: git, github, repository

I have been using a Git repository for a couple years and still feel like a newb..  help is most welcome!

It starts cloning for a while:

```
remote: Counting objects: 22394<br>
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12314/12314)<br>
Receiving objects: 32% ....
```

The error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200<br>
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly<br>
fatal: early EOF<br>
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The git command:

```
git clone https://[username]:[password]@github.com/MegaWorldStudios/OmegatechV2.git "C:\OmegatechV2"
```

Git Version:
1.9.4-preview20140929 (downloaded/updated today from the git fellas)

I found questions such as this one, but none of the answers solves the problem.

I've also tried:
Setting the postBuffer higher as mentioned from similar posts

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000<br>
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Setting --depth 1 and doing a shallow clone that I can later pull the rest

Setting --depth 2

```
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
Cloning from a branch other than the main branch
Reinstalling the software and updating
```

What does this infernal error mean and what's the fix/workaround?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Anti-Virus? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442734/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200

Comment: Could you try using an ssh url? (if you can add your public key to this private repo) `git clone git@github.com:MegaWorldStudios/OmegatechV2`

Comment: Possibly relevant http://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-falied-when-connecting-to-https-servers/187199#187199

Answer (score 18):

This error occurs due to Git's HTTPS protocol. To view the error in detail, you can set the `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` environment variable. For example:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git pull
```

Your Antivirus or Firewall could be modifying the HTTP packets in transit. See [git clone failed due to antivirus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442734/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200) for example.

Finally, it could be an unreliable network connection. I am using an OSX machine connected to Wifi, and the problem disappeared when I switch to a LAN connection.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, and it turned out a VPN client (that was off at the time) was messing with the traffic somehow.

Comment: I had the same problem but was solved reinstalling cntlm

Comment: I had the exact same problem on wifi. Unbeliveable but changing to network cable it started working...

Comment: After 3 days of straggling and trying any workaround out there, our IT guys agreed to reboot their F5 load balancer - and voilà - everything is back to normal !

Comment: what the actual... ? setting `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` actually removed the issue entirely for me.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar error. Tried to configure `http.postBuffer` but it didn't work.

I found about the same error (with solution) over here: [Git Clone Fails - error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=693897332)

As suggested in the above link, I solved it out by using SSH to perform the clone.

Here is a good tutorial on how to [Setup SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html).

Answer (score 2):

Git clone with a HTTPS url is not supported by the git binary shipped currently in debian and ubuntu. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643413/1576149) for a workround.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem specific to **Atlassian Stash** and **Mac OSX** git client. Workaround:

1. Install HomeBrew following the instructions here: http://brew.sh/
2. Follow the solution provided in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/entropiae/a899d8a78dc8a38f505e) courtesy of entropiae:

   ```
   $ brew remove git
   $ brew remove curl

   $ brew install openssl
   $ brew install --with-openssl curl
   $ brew install --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl git
   ```

   (this installs a working binary in eg `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.10.2/bin/git`)
3. Tell your IDE to use that binary, or you can run it from the command line to clone / push etc

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on Mac OSX when attempting push my code to bitbucket. I made 2 following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Increase the buffer with command: 
   git config http.postBuffer 524288000
2. Change protocol from HTTPS to SSH. This is the main key to resolve the issue. You can refer to https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting here because this was one of the first Google results for 'RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200'.*

I tried many different things to get this issue resolved. I tried compiling git from source, adding gitconfig settings, and I even tried multiple configurations of my GitLab server. None of these things worked. I didn't understand why I could clone a repo successfully on the same subnet as my git server, but couldn't over a remote subnet (connected by site-to-site VPN).

The issue ended up being my firewall. I white-listed the client and everything started working. Temporarily placing the client in a DMZ may also be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while cloning a very large repository. I tried with configuring http.postBuffer, but it did not work for me.
Finally, it was issue with my internet.

**I connected my laptop to a high speed Internet and it cloned successfully!**