# Is there a OneDrive API for C++?

Tags: c++, onedrive

I want to make a script that allows me to upload and download my files from OneDrive using C++ for a backup project I am making.

I came across the [REST](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/releases/view/146873) API however I cannot seem to download it. This is what I mean.

[image]

If it helps I am on a Mac running OS X Yosemite.

This will also be a command line application

Answer (score 3):

If you look closer at the project you'll see that the source code is there, and detailed instructions on how to build it can be found in the documentation:

[How to setup, build, and run tests on OSX](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20OSX&referringTitle=Documentation).

And here's the documentation on how to use the REST API with OneDrive:

[Using the REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659752.aspx)

Comment: What shall I do now? The link they give (https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca) returns a 404 page not found. What shall I do now?

Comment: @aPyDeveloper Did you follow the instructions and used git to clone the repository? It worked for me when I did `git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca` The cloning finished with `Checking out files: 100% (1021/1021), done.`

Comment: When I go to `https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca` on the web it still says page not found and I still can't clone it

Comment: @aPyDeveloper You have to use git to clone it; you can't browse the url. You could download the source directly though from the download link in the menu https://casablanca.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#

Comment: I still get `error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200` when `git clone`ing it

Comment: @aPyDeveloper I have no idea why you get that error, sorry. There are some questions here on SO about this problem though, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197171/git-clone-repository-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200 and see if it helps. Also, this discussion on Codeplex might help: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/workitem/26133

Comment: I could still do the direct download though.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper Yes, you should be able to download the source and build it according to the instructions.

Comment: Yea. I ment to say that it worked. Its the way how I wrote it. Sorry for the confusion!