# 'pod install' is getting stuck at 'Receiving Objects'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using Xcode 8.3.3.

I'm trying to install the firebase pods for Push Notifications for IOS and can't get past the 'pod install' command. 'Receiving objects' is getting stuck at - what seem like - random percentages.

This is what the terminal output looks like:

```
Mac-Admin:MKR Medwe$ pod install --verbose
Preparing

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
$ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Counting objects: 1447009, done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (315/315), done.        
Receiving objects:  12% (183211/1447009), 36.09 MiB | 2.11 MiB/s
```

I've tried cancelling and restarting but that doesn't help either.

After waiting for about 30min I received this error:

```
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
(/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress

Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Counting objects: 1447009, done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (315/315), done.        
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806.11 MiB/s    
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
)
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

As the error suggests, I've tried adding the problematic 'master' source manually. But I'm stuck with the same problem as before. Also getting the same error after about 20-30min.

**[EDIT]**
This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.3'

target 'MKR' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  target 'MKRTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MKRUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you show your `Podfile`? Do you have `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` as the first line there? Also, just in case - is your internet connection stable when accesing github via a browser?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197171/git-clone-repository-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200

Comment: @Losiowaty I've added it to the question. Though I don't see how the podfile could affect the manual approach?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thanks very much, but I can't find a working solution there either. I'll make sure to clearly state it when I eventually do find one.

Comment: Have you tried adding `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` as the first line in your `Podfile`?

Comment: Maybe you should try and install the latest version of git (just a thought)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I couldn't get the cocoa pods approach to work. But installing the frameworks manually worked for me.

Since the explanation on the Firebase page is kinda sloppy I've relied on this blog post: http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/setting-up-firebase-without-cocoapods/

The post provides a quite elaborate explanation! It doesn't solve the git/cocoa pods problem but it does solve the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing by [Cocoapods App](https://cocoapods.org/app)

> Have easy access to running pod install and pod update on your
>   projects. It also supports running every CocoaPods command via a
>   hosted ruby environment.

Comment: Nice looking app but it also gets stuck at "Receiving objects". Problem is caused by Github servers, which apply a bandwidth/CPU limit on cocoapods Sepcs repo.