# git clone from GitHub RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code

Tags: git, github

When I clone a repository from GitHub, I met this error. I have tried a lot of times and I never succeed.

```
git clone https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x.git
Cloning into 'cocos2d-x'...
remote: Counting objects: 397914, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 MiB | 0 bytes/s      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I have taken a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442734/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200), but I don't have Avast installed. How can I solve it?

Edit:

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005259/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-0) , I have increased my git buffer by running this command `git config --global http.postBuffer 2M`.

I am using Mac OSX, under zsh.

Comment: Do you get the same error when cloning the same repository using ssh url? `git clone git@github.com:cocos2d/cocos2d-x.git`

Comment: After I tried to set git buffer, It seems worked.

Comment: @einverne So please post this as self-answer.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github). Probably you have some large files (larger than `http.postBuffer`) in your repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005259/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried for several times after I set git buffer, as I mentioned in the question, it seems work now.

So if you met this error, run this command:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 2M
```

and then try again for some times.

Reference:

[git push error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005259/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-0)