# Clone from Jenkins fails. Clone from Command Line works

Tags: git, jenkins

When I run c:\git\bin\git.exe clone https://username:password@repo-URL from Jenkins, it fails with these messages:

```
    Cloning into '365Agile.Portal'...
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    fatal: index-pack failed
    error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

    d:\Workspaces\Ranorex>exit 128 
    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

When I use the same line from Command Line, it works fine.
Result:

```
    Receiving objects: 100% (21540/21540), 76.16 MiB | 2.77 MiB/s, done. 
    Resolving deltas: 100% (4375/4375), done. Checking connectivity... done. 
    Checking out files: 100% (1233/1233), done.
```

What is it's problem?

Using:
Jenkins 1.618
Git Version 2.7.0

Update: This morning I ran the Build again and it worked properly WITHOUT me tweaking anything. I am guessing something has gone on outside of my control, like a problem, with the Source Control Repository or something. A bit unsatisfying really, as I don't yet know the culprit.

Comment: Same machine? Have you tried cloning using ssh? Are you running Avast?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169300/git-clone-from-github-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442734/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200

Comment: The Command Line stuff was done on the Jenkins Slave machine. The Jenkins runs on another machine.

Comment: Jenkins version, Git version, git plugin version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed